# Javascript regex that requires one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one number, and allows special

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to check a password field, I want to require at least one uppercase letter, one lower case letter and one number.

I also want to allow the user to use special characters, but I don't want special characters to be a requirement.

Is this possible and if so, what regex should I use?

Comment: (That's not what makes a good password: https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/)

Comment: Please do a search before posting - this question has been asked and answered many times. e.g. In this case search: "JavaScript Password Validation"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want special characters to be a requirement, there is no point validating it.

This regex should do: `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*$/`

Note that this regex will not validate properly for characters not in the default ascii range of a-zA-Z. So if my password was `åäöÅÄÖ1234` it would not be valid for this regex, even though there are upper case and lower case letters.

A possible solution, if this is a requirement, would be to rewrite using unicode properties.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/uO6jB5

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'd tried some that did not validate the special characters but seemed to block them, I will try his one and see

Comment: Why do you use the `/g`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Don't know, shouldn't be there. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say you should not allow Unicode characters in passwords, as normalization issues may make passwords not matching.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://regexlib.com/%28A%2813E-t-BjvZ-WvDNI3kEXWexqe-dnRabCLhUJT4HCwiq39cFxk1bCp2xTgMv4ZLuwh4z02qwn-LwirPbo_Y1NF6Tnx6zEJKJ9ukU7WXcOnRM1%29%29/Search.aspx?k=password&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1):

*"Password matching expression. Password must be at least 4 characters, no more than 8 characters, and must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, and one numeric digit."*

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}$
```

(note: you'll want to test this to be sure.)