# test() regex function not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble figuring out why this function works in chrome, but not IE:

```
function isOkPass(p){
    var categories = 0;
    var anUpperCase = /[A-Z]/;
    var aLowerCase = /[a-z]/; 
    var aNumber = /[0-9]/;
    var aSpecial = /[!|@|#|$|%|^|&|*|(|)|-|_]/;
    var obj = {};
    obj.result = true;

    if(p.length < 8){
        obj.result=false;
        obj.error="Password not long enough!"
        return obj;
    }

    var numUpper = 0;
    var numLower = 0;
    var numNums = 0;
    var numSpecials = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){
        if(anUpperCase.test(p[i])) {
            numUpper++;
console.dir('UPPPER');
        } else if(aLowerCase.test(p[i])) {
            numLower++;
console.dir('LOWEERR');
        } else if(aNumber.test(p[i])) {
            numNums++;
console.dir('NUMBER');
        } else if(aSpecial.test(p[i])) {
            numSpecials++;
console.dir('special');
        }
    }

    if(numUpper >= 1){
        categories += 1;
    }
    if(numLower >= 1){
        categories += 1;
    }
    if(numNums >= 1){
        categories += 1;
    }
    if(numSpecials >= 1){
        categories += 1;
    }

    if(categories < 3){
        obj.categories= categories;
        obj.result= false;
        obj.error= "Password not complex enough!";
        return obj;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The user enters a password in an input box and when they click out of the box the string is validated with this function. In chrome it works fine, but in IE it appears `test()` is behaving strangely.

I added some debug messages and found that when I enter a number in the input box (and click out of it) IE displays the `"LOWER"` debug message where as chrome displays the `"NUMBER"` debug message as expected. What's wrong with my code?

Edit: after you guys pointed out the stupidity of how the string was being evaluated (I think I grabbed a script that was originally supposed to record every type of character) I'm now just doing this:

```
if(aUpperCase.test(p)) {
    numUpper++;
};
if(aLowerCase.test(p)) {
    numLower++;
};
if(aNumber.test(p)) {
    numNums++;
};
if(aSpecial.test(p)) {
    numSpecials++;
};
```

Comment: You don't need those `|` characters in `/[!|@|#|$|%|^|&|*|(|)|-|_]/`.

Comment: Why do you have alternation operators `|` inside your character class `[]`?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, "complexity" tests like this are a bad idea. A ten-character all-lower-case password made up of randomly-chosen letters is a strong password, but this test won't allow it.

Comment: What are you passing in for `p`? I don't see any regex issues, but maybe you're not passing in the input's text correctly.

Comment: @Pointy Very true, Complexity never out ways Length in a brute force attack. Just make them have long passwords and you're secure 99% of the time.

Comment: The issue isn't IE it is your regex.

Comment: I'm not getting this logic at all. You're running the regex's on **each individual character**--why?

Comment: You're indexing into a string, which isn't supported in some versions of IE. Try `p.charAt(i)`. Or make sure you're in IE Standars Mode.

Comment: It has to match the password policy of our IDM platform (Active Directory). These are the default complexity requirements of AD (minus password history).

Comment: [This Q and A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586480/javascript-regex-that-requires-one-uppercase-letter-one-lowercase-letter-and-on) may help you do it with a single regex.

Comment: p.charAt(i) was what I needed. As squint said I was attempting to index into a string which chrome allowed, but IE didn't. And now to delete this question as per the down vote.

Comment: Probably more important is to make sure you're in standards mode. IE 8 and up should allow string indexing, but not in quirks mode. Do you have a doctype for your HTML document?

Comment: I did not have a doctype! Thanks for that I usually make sure of this, but forgot this time.

Comment: Now, you don't need `p.charAt(i)`. You **don't need to regexp your string one character at a time**. Think about it. Running the `test` against the **whole string** will succeed if there's a least one character of the given type, which is what you want.

Comment: @torazaburo is right. While the `.charAt()` or the doctype solves the immediate problem, your overall approach can be improved. But +1 because it's a good, detailed question.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, must admit I just copied most of this snippet and made sure it worked without checking the sanity of the thing.